# Java Application is not responding after using Thread.Sleep();

Tags: java, multithreading, canvas, swt, freeze

I am currently having some trouble when running the follwing code. If I delete this part the problems disappear so this part of my whole code has to be the problem. It runs and draws what I want perfectly but after a few seconds (maxAddedRuntime is set via user (milliseconds)) the application freezes for a while (window is not responding Windows message) and starts over with drawing after waiting approximately the same time while the window is frozen. What do I do wrong?
I am using SWT and a canvas to draw. Thank you for your help

```
public void drawNetwork(Canvas canvas, GC gc, Network network, Shell shlNetworkVisualizer) {        
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    endTime = startTime + maxAddedRuntime;
    this.drawNetworkAlg1(canvas, gc, network);
    int canvasHeight = canvas.getBounds().height;
    int canvasWidth = canvas.getBounds().width;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis()<endTime) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight); //ClearCanvas basically
        for (Nodek: network.node) {
            //drawSomeStuff
        }
        for (Edge k: network.edges) {
            //alsoDrawSomeStuff
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're sleeping inside the Event Dispatch Thread. (EDT).  That is where all events including painting are processed.  So you are locking up your GUI.  Never sleep inside the EDT.  Keep all processing to a minimum.

Comment: move sleep to end of loop

Comment: @AnsarOzden moving the sleep will not help, the UI thread will still be blocked until the loop ends.

Answer (score 3):

An SWT app must return to the main `Display.readAndDispatch` loop as quickly as possible. So you cannot use a loop with a `Thread.sleep` call - this will just lock up the UI until the loop ends.

Instead you can use `Display.timerExec` to run code after a delay. You would use this to run a single step (just one gc.fillRectange for example) and then call `Display.timerExec` again to schedule the next step.

```
public void timerExec(int milliseconds, Runnable runnable)
```

Note: The GC you receive from a paint event is only valid during the paint. The timerExec call should normally just call `redraw` on the canvas to cause a new paint event to be generated.

Here is a simple class that does basic timerExec calls and paints:

```
class Progress
{
  private final Canvas canvas;
  private final long endTime;

  Progress(Canvas c)
  {
    canvas = c;

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1_000;

    canvas.addListener(SWT.Paint, this::paint);

    canvas.getDisplay().timerExec(100, this::timer);
  }

  private void paint(Event event)
  {
    GC gc = event.gc;

    int canvasHeight = canvas.getBounds().height;
    int canvasWidth = canvas.getBounds().width;

    gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // TODO more painting
  }


  private void timer()
  {
    if (canvas.isDisposed()) {  // Don't continue if control closed
      return;
    }

    canvas.redraw();

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
      canvas.getDisplay().timerExec(100, this::timer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did a new runnable with all the code I want to be repeated in it and called the timerExec while System.currentTimeMillis<endTime. I now get an Error saying "org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Graphic is disposed" on Line where I call gc.fillrectangle[..]

What do I still do wrong?

Comment: You are using a GC which is no longer valid. You should probably be using the timerExec to just call `redraw` on the canvas and do the actual drawing in a paint listener where you will have a valid GC.

Comment: Ive now moved everything except the actual painting out of the shown code and added it into my original paintListener. I does draw now and there are no errors. If I call canvas.redraw() the application crashes and I dont know why

Comment: Crashes how? What error? Ask a new question showing what you are doing now and describing the error.

Comment: timerExec does not repeat. You have to call it again each time, it is up to you to decide if you want call it again separately.

Comment: I cant understand timerExec correctly. I put System.out.println("Test"); in the Runnable and called timerExec from a while (true) with 500ms delay. Application just crashes (No Response from Window). What the Hell do I do wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223357/discussion-between-premaider-and-greg-449).

Comment: I don't do chat. I have added a simple example